# How to get all element siblings in an array in jQuery...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what i would like to do is get all element siblings in a variable in Jquery to have easy access of all its sibling's properties.
As you can see the structure, the siblings don't have ids or classes or even any attributes on them apart from the tag name,
but how would i get the element with id=>the_only_id_element to return all its siblings without using
**$('#the_only_id_element').next().next()** .....?

```
<div id="the_only_id_element"> element one </div>
<div> element two </div>
<div> element three </div>
<div> element four </div>
```

Comment: `.siblings().toArray()`?

Comment: a quick google search of *"jquery siblings"* would have answered this for you

Comment: _"what i would like to do is get all element siblings in a variable"_ All of the siblings, or only `div` siblings which contain text "element"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//This one is tested!
var element = $('#the_only_id_element'),
  required_html = $(element).nextUntil(element, 0); //returns array / siblings after each other in array...


//now use array index selector to select any sibling by its position
console.log($(required_html[0]).html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="the_only_id_element"> element one </div>
<div> element two </div>
<div> element three </div>
<div> element four </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$('#the_only_id_element').siblings()
```

Depends on your expectations you can pass as an param the selector.

Demo:

```js
console.log($("#the_only_id_element").siblings());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="the_only_id_element"> element one </div>
<div> element two </div>
<div> element three </div>
<div> element four </div>
```